# Rabbitmq move message to different queue if processing fails

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

I am working with RabbitMq .net and the message acknowledgements. If the consumer is able to process the message we can send back an ack in the form of

```
channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
```

which will take it off the queue. I would like to move the message to the "error-queue" if I have issues with deserialization

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
```

I have tried using "x-dead-letter-exchange" but it depends on "x-message-ttl" time setting. I do only want to move messages to error-queue if processing fails. How to achieve this funcationality? I couldn't find any help online.

Comment: dead-letter exchange is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your consumer rejects the message using `basic.reject` or `basic.nack` with the `requeue` flag set to `false`, RabbitMQ will republish the message to the dead-letter exchange. This is [documented in the article about dead-letter exchanges](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

Here are the functions to reject or nack messages in the RabbitMQ .NET 3.6.10 client:

- [`BasicNack(ulong deliveryTag, bool multiple, bool requeue)`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.10/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.10-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.BasicNack(System.UInt64,System.Boolean,System.Boolean))
- [`BasicReject(ulong deliveryTag, bool requeue)`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.10/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.10-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.BasicReject(System.UInt64,System.Boolean))